# Bundle install with mysql2 not finishing in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this stack trace:

```
Fetching mysql2 0.3.21
Installing mysql2 0.3.21 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling infile.c
compiling client.c
client.c:439:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:441:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:762:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:793:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:794:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:797:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:798:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:799:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:830:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1185:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
10 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.21/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any idea what is going on? I cannot run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`. If I do I get:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling infile.c
compiling client.c
client.c:439:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:441:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:762:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:793:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:794:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:797:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:798:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:799:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:830:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1185:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
10 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jwan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.21/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the log, you are using mysql version `8.0.12` but version `0.3.21` of `mysql2` gem is not compatible with it. You should either install a newer version of `mysql2` gem (Newer than 0.4.10 should be fine) or move to older version of mysql.

**Install using command:**

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

**Using bundle:**

`gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'`

`bundle update mysql2`

**Note:** If you are using rails 4.x then you should use `mysql2` version `0.4.10` instead of the newest version.

Comment: Where am I using 8.0.12? Is that the mysql on my local computer?

Comment: @Jwan622 That's right, you could check your mysql version using this command.
`mysql --version`

Comment: Is there anyway for me to use a version of mysql compatible with gem  0.3.21?

Comment: Using mysql 5.7 should be fine. Take a look at this link
https://medium.com/yish/homebrew-mysql-8-0-downgrade-to-mysql-5-7-1145850987cd

Comment: I'm just a little new sorry... I ran these two commands: `brew reinstall mysql@5.7` and `brew unlink mysql` successfully. What do I do next to point to this older version of mysql so that it is connected when I run `gem install mysql2`?